# How to return rows only if there is more than one result

Tags: sql, oracle

In a Oracle 10g database, I would like to build a SQL query that returns the result rows only if there is more than one row result.

Is it possible and how ?

Comment: why do you want to do this? Is there a reason you couldnt do this logic outside of the query?

Comment: i suggest you to check size of list your query will return.

Comment: The logic has to be inside the SQL query because this one is used by another framework that we can't add logic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to count the number of returned results, if you dont want to make a group by, you can use the following :

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT col1,
               col2,
               COUNT(*) OVER() cnt
          FROM your_table
         WHERE <conditions> )
 WHERE cnt > 1
```

Comment: Doesn't this need an identifier as well?  Will it work just as it is?  I had to add something like the following to make it work... `SELECT * FROM (SELECT col1, col2, COUNT(*) cnt FROM your_table WHERE <conditions>) AS tInfo WHERE tInfo.cnt > 1;`.

Comment: This is correct

SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT col1,
      col2, 
      COUNT(*) OVER() cnt 
   FROM your_table WHERE <conditions>) AS tInfo
WHERE tInfo.cnt > 1;

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from 
  (select column1,column2,column3,
    (select count(*) from table1 where '*XYZ Condition*' ) as rowCount 
  from table1 where '*XYZ Condition*') 
where rowCount > 1;
```

You just need to put same condition at both place in query i.e. '*XYZ Condition*' is same at both `where` clause.

Comment: That works but it does the same query two times (two "where" conditions).

Answer (score 0):

Do you need like the following result?

```
c1   c2
1    AA
1    BB
2    CC
```

result:

```
c1   c2
1    AA,BB
2    CC
```

The following can meet your requirements.

```
select c1,ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(c2,','),',') from (
  select c1,c2, row_number() over(partition by c1 order by c2)rn, 
                     count(*) over(partition by id ) cnt from XXX  -- XXX: your table
                 ) a  where level=cnt
              start with rn=1  connect by prior c1=c1 and prior rn=rn-1
```

Comment: It doesn't correspond to my requirements.